# Starting two instances of jetty with different maven (war)modules

Tags: maven, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-8

I have a multi-module maven project, of which two modules generate wars. Both serverModules depend on persistenceModule. Each server module is configured with its own jetty-maven-plugin which bring the server up during pre-integration-test phase and stops it during post-integration-test. Each serer module has its own jetty configurations- login services & ports.

```
    --trunk
          |_serverModuleA
          |_serverModuleB
          |_persistenceModule
```

serverModuleB has some integration tests, which invoke services provided in serverModuleA. So, it is required that serverModuleA is up and running while integration tests in serverModuleB are executed.

I cannot bring up two jetty instances, from serverModuleB, as jetty-maven-plugin does not support it. 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: When you're running your tests, does it *really* matter that the apps are in different physical servers? I mean, do your tests not pass if they're run in a single instance? I understand that your production configuration may actually require two servers, but your tests may not...

Comment: Both serverModules have the persistence module packaged into their war. So, I ran into a problem with conflicting persistence-unit names(not being unique), when I tried that.